# Proper way to map the object

Tags: go

I have a simple task.

1. Array of people object comes in, up to a thousand.
2. Need to iterate over it, and create a custom payload for external service.

I have created a working solution, but I would like to see if I am totally off course, and what changes should I make.

I have reduced non-important details from the code (errors, and similar), so it might not work. But the point is to show how it works, and hopefully get some advice.

```
User struct {
   Name        string  `json:"name"`
   Lastname    string  `json:"lastname"`
 }

func HandleLambda(event events.SQSEvent) {
 var userRecords []map[string]interface{}

 for idx := range event.Records {
  record := event.Records[idx]
  ev, err := e.NewEvent(record.Body)
  
  if err != nil {
    continue
  }

  u, err := repository.NewUser(ev)

  if err != nil {
        continue
  }

  user := make(map[string]interface{})
  user["1"] = u.Name
  user["2"] = u.Lastname

  userRecords = append(userRecords, user)
  }

 uJSON, _ := json.Marshal(userRecords)
 // I send this to external service

 }
```

External service is using numbers as keys, that's why I need "1" and "2". I do not have control over it.
That's the way it works.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You mentioned you removed non-important details, but it would actually be really good to see the fully, working code, you might never know what review comments you get about those non-essentials. Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I might as well then.  To prefix that with:  It looks fine as is,
there's a few details that could be improved, although those also depend
on your team and style guide.  Also read it in the context of a bigger
project, not everything always applies, especially if it's one-off code,
etc.

I'm gonna assume (since the formatting is a bit off) that you're using
`gofmt` or `goimports` already, if you don't, check them out, it helps
immensely.

For the `User` struct, even if the JSON name is `lastname`, consider the
Go-side name to be `LastName` to keep in line with normal style guides.
Depending on whether you need it the JSON annotation could also use an
`omitempty`, but that depends on your external service of course.

For the `HandleLambda` loop a few things stand out:

- `for idx := range event.Records` might as well be
  `for idx, record := event.Records`, no need have an extra line to get
  the actual item.  And if you're never using it,
  `for _, record := event.Records` even.
- Errors are ignored?  Consider logging them if don't error our
  immediately.
- `user := make(map ...)` I'd usually make that a literal to avoid
  repeating myself even more.
- `userRecords` could perhaps already be pre-allocated to the right size. Then there'd be no need for `append` at all.  Or, like here, if you still need to use `continue`, pre-allocating the maximum length it could take, so it definitely wouldn't have to
  be resized might also be a good idea.  Usually this also doesn't matter that much if you don't have a
  lot of entries, but it's good to keep in mind for situations where it
  *does* matter.
- Also consider making the to-map conversion a new method on `User`, or
  a helper function, you might want to test it or reuse in other places.
- `repository` looks like a global variable, that's usually not the best
  idea.  Consider making that a parameter for `HandleLambda`, or making
  `HandleLambda` a method and put the `repository` as one of its
  members.  It will help with testability in the end to not have
  dependencies scattered around like that.

```golang
type User struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    LastName string `json:"lastname"`
}

func (u *User) toMap() map[string]interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "1": u.Name,
        "2": u.LastName,
    }
}

func HandleLambda(event events.SQSEvent) {
    userRecords := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0, len(event.Records))

    for _, record := range event.Records {
        ev, err := event.NewEvent(record.Body)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        user, err := repository.NewUser(ev)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        userRecords = append(userRecords, user.toMap())
    }

    uJSON, _ := json.Marshal(userRecords)
    // I send this to external service
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I learned new things from your answer! Thank you.

Comment: I have one question. You mentioned:
"userRecords could already be pre-allocated to the right size, then there'd be no need for append,". But append is still used?

Comment: @Wexoni yes, given that `continue` is used, it doesn't seem likely that the final length can be set immediately, however, normally I'd have expected that those errors would not just be skipped. I'll add a note. Suffice to say creating the slice with an upper bound is probably good, although if lots of entries would be skipped, perhaps even worse than allocating nothing at all upfront. That's something only more knowledge about the actual data would reveal.

Comment: Not many errors will be skipped. This comes form AWS SQS. I think I will keep only one error check, the first one that checks the record.body, Second one is my mistake and it should not be there at all.

Comment: On a side note, when you declared that slice. I was able to find and read about it. But that zero is confusing me. What is it?

Comment: @Wexoni yeah, if you haven't come across it so far, take a look at https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make - it's basically initialising the length of the slice to zero, but the capacity to something else, so `append` will simply make use of that capacity.

Comment: I tried to implement the suggestions, but I run in a problem. The to Map() function, in my IDE (Goland) it has many issues, it seems it is a Syntax Error that creates them all. I tried, but I cant fix it. Do you maybe have an idea?

Comment: @Wexoni yeah I missed a few parentheses, should be fixed now above.